# How to fix macro to still continue after #value

Tags: excel, vba

i created a macro where if the the cell if blank i put "N/A" in the empty cell. i do this through multiple worksheets. the problem i am coming across is some worksheets have formulas in it that lead to "#value!" which then leads to an error on my macro. Is there anyway around that, i tried something but it does not work.

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Integer
Dim r As Long, c As Long
'Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = 6 To Worksheets.Count


    For c = 1 To 14
    For r = 5 To 1000
        If Sheets(i).Cells(r, c) = "" Or "#value!" Then
        Sheets(i).Cells(r, c).Value = "N/A"
        End If

    Next r
    Next c
Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: FWIW I would strongly advise *against* using the string value `N/A` if the error value means to have a semantic meaning elsewhere in the worksheet, or in other VBA code: the error value `#N/A` (as returned by the `NA()` worksheet function, or by `CVErr(xlErrNA)` in VBA) is considered an error value (like `#VALUE!` and `#REF!` and others), which you can then locate with the `IsError` function in VBA; `#N/A` error values work with `ISNA`, `ISERROR`, and `IFERROR` worksheet functions; the string value `N/A` does not convey that meaning to the rest of the worksheet/code.

Answer (score 2):

Test for the Error first:

```
IF iserror(Sheets(i).Cells(r, c)) Then
    Sheets(i).Cells(r, c).Value = "N/A"
ElseIF Sheets(i).Cells(r, c) = "" Then
    Sheets(i).Cells(r, c).Value = "N/A"
End If
```

Comment: ++ Nice. I would prefer `Len(Trim(Sheets(i).Cells(r, c))) = 0` to `Sheets(i).Cells(r, c) = ""` though :)

Comment: BTW another 6k for the coffee mug ;)

Comment: @SiddharthRout we all need goals, and striving for a free coffee mug is mine. :)  As to the preference, will that also take into account formulas that return an empty string?  Seems like it should and would probably be better in case the formula returns `" "` with a space.

Comment: @SiddharthRout [life goal: 200K](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261514/1188513)

Comment: I like that T-Shirt @MathieuGuindon :P